# Transfer files between Android and Linux

Tags: android, ubuntu

I'm trying to find an app (or 2, one for each device) to transfer files between my Android and a desktop running Ubuntu (basically to backup pics, videos or notes from the phone).

I'd prefer something that's in the Ubuntu repository and Google Play without ads and for free. And I would like a cli app, so, to automatize copying data from phone into the desktop each x hours.

I tried `adb` until my phone decided to block all USB connections from my desktop. I suppose there's a way of troubleshooting this, but so far nothing works, tried changing several setting. I'd prefer something that will just work and won't make me worry that it will stop working.

Desktop has no Bluetooth. Right now, I just store information on a microSD card and transfer it through it.

Comment: For your USB/ADB issue I'd recommend visiting our [Android sister site](https://android.stackexchange.com/). I'm optimistic that can be helped. For your backup software, see below :)

Answer (score 2):

As you're using Linux on your PC (good choice btw!), you have `rsync` in its repository and maybe even already installed. A pendant on Android could e.g. be **[Syncopoli](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/)**:

[image] [image]
<sup>Syncopoli (source: [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

This seems to be made for your purpose, as the screenshots show – the example matches your need for photos, but document locations can be added the same way. According to its description it is a one-way sync, but by your question you need it for backup, so it should be fine. Authentication is possible via password or public key, both things you're most likely familiar with as Linux user.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to transfer files from my Android phone and USB is acting up, I use [Cx File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cxinventor.file.explorer&hl=de&gl=US&pli=1), which has a feature to open an FTP server which you can then access from your desktop.

Comment: Thanks. This perfectly answers [my question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84538/gratis-full-file-system-bidirectional-file-transfer-between-windows-and-android).  Feel free to post an answer there and I will accept it.