# Gratis full file system bidirectional file transfer between Windows and Android

Tags: windows, gratis, android, file-management

There is no shortage of apps to backup contacts, photos, calendar, videos, etc from Android to PC.

I am looking for one (gratis) that allows me access to the full file system - in both directions.

Beyond that, I don't care e.g whether it uses USB cable, WiFi, BlueTooth. A slight bonus might be searching for file name/contents, but I can achieve that with other tools, so it is just a convenience, not a requirement.

Comment: Full file system access requires a rooted Android device. Is your Android device rooted?

Comment: Yes, it is. Technically, I don't require the ***full*** file system, just more than the standard contacts, emails, photo, video, music, etc which most apps offer.

Comment: Contacts and Emails you won't find in the file system. Further, talking of bi-directional: as long as it's just "your documents", I see no issue – but as soon as it goes beyond that: I doubt that Windows understand the Unix file permissions, so after sycning back those might need to be adjusted (to what, and how should the sync tool know?). That said: did you take a look at my corresponding app listing? [Synchronizing Files and Folders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync) – the SMB-section would be the one you're most interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to transfer files from my Android phone and USB is acting up, I use [Cx File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cxinventor.file.explorer&hl=de&gl=US&pli=1), which has a feature to open an FTP server which you can then access from your desktop.